# Splitting multiple XML elements from a single file into multiple files

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

I have a file that looks something like this.

```
a
B abc
c abc
d abc
e abc
<stuff></stuff><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><element><moreelements>1</moreelements></element>

a
B abc
c abc
d abc
e abc
<stuff></stuff><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><element><moreelements>1234</moreelements></element>

a
B abc
c abc
d abc
e abc
<stuff></stuff><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><element><moreelements>12354</moreelements></element>

a
B abc
c abc
d abc
e abc
<stuff></stuff><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><element><moreelements>12534</moreelements></element>

a
B abc
c abc
d abc
e abc
<stuff></stuff><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><element><moreelements>12634</moreelements></element>
```

With a large number, say 1000+  of similar items repeated.

I want to read the file, extract every `<element>` into its own file.

So with the 1 file I want to create multiple files that contain text like:

```
<element><moreelements>1</moreelements></element>
```

I'd prefer to keep the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` but it's not a requirement.

So if `<element>....</element>` is repeated in 1 file 1000 times, I want to turn it into 1000 files.

I'm sure there's a way with unix utilities like awk or sed but I'm not sure how to accomplish it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `gawk` hack...

```
$ tag="element>"; awk -v RS="</?$tag" -v t="$tag" '
       !(NR%2){print "<"t $0 "</"t > "element_"++c".xml"}' file

$ head element_*

==> element_1.xml <==
<element><moreelements>1</moreelements></element>

==> element_2.xml <==
<element><moreelements>1234</moreelements></element>

==> element_3.xml <==
<element><moreelements>12354</moreelements></element>

==> element_4.xml <==
<element><moreelements>12534</moreelements></element>

==> element_5.xml <==
<element><moreelements>12634</moreelements></element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative ***gawk*** approach:

```
awk '$0~/<element>/{match($0, /<element>.+<\/element>/); 
     print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) > "el_"++c".xml"}' file
```

---

```
head el_*
==> el_1.xml <==
<element><moreelements>1</moreelements></element>

==> el_2.xml <==
<element><moreelements>1234</moreelements></element>

==> el_3.xml <==
<element><moreelements>12354</moreelements></element>

==> el_4.xml <==
<element><moreelements>12534</moreelements></element>

==> el_5.xml <==
<element><moreelements>12634</moreelements></element>
```

---

`$0~/<element>/` - to consider only lines with `<element>` tag

`match($0, /<element>.+<\/element>/)` - matching an entire `<element>` tag

Comment: you assume start/end tag on the same line.  Perhaps add `-v RS=` to extend the record boundaries.